# Getting less impressions than my website's position in search results would suggest

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

I have a site that ranks 3rd for the term "e decorating". According to google's keyword tool that gets 12,000 monthly impressions.

However, according to google's webmaster's tools, I'm only getting 35 impression for that term. Why is this?

Comment: Your image links return "403 Forbidden" errors.

Comment: ...and so, apparently, do most images and JS/CSS files on your website. You _might_ want to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the site only shows up third for you. There are many factors that determine search placement, including your location, previous searches etc.

I also believe that the 12,000 number includes searches with other terms, eg "e decorating website", "e decorating in [location]" and so on. So there may be 12,000 searches globally, but you only show up for a small number of them.

Comment: Yes, make sure to uncheck "Broad" match and check "Exact" match on the left hand side in the Keyword Tools. Also, to check your position when seaerching, you can add `&pws=0` to the URL to remove some, but not all, personalization.